# Accessing file in method that is created in another method in java

Tags: java, methods, file-handling

I'm beginner and new to java. I  am making a java project. And I'm using file handling in it. I want to ask a question that if I have created a certain file in one method, can I access that file and its content in another method? If yes then how?Thanks in advance!

I an trying to do this. But don't know what is correct way to do it.

Comment: You don't 'hold files open' in Java, so just open the file again in the other method

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can store this file in a variable, which will be accessible for both methods.

Or, if the file producing method returns this file as a result, you can call this method inside the another method

Comment: The question itself is unclear we should ask more details about such question before answering.